# Using get_terms() to list terms from one custom taxonomy AND from one specific built-in category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, page-template, terms

I'm trying to get the terms of a taxonomy (kind) and the number of content they have but only for a specific category (get_parent_page_slug() = city name = category slug). This is what I have so far:

```
    $args = array(
    //          'taxonomy' => 'tipo',
                'hide_empty' => 1,
            );
    $terms = get_terms('kind', $args);

    //var_dump($terms);exit;

    $count = count($terms);
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/' . get_parent_page_slug() . '/' . $pagename . '/' . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">Todos (' . $count . ')</a></li>';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/' . get_parent_page_slug() . '/' . $pagename . '/?tipo=' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . ' ('. $term->count .')</a></li>';
    }
    echo '<ul>';
```

Just in case I clarify: I'm doing this in a page template. The results I expect are these:

> Accommodation in City Name
>
> - All (5)
> - Hotel (1)
> - Inn (2)
> - Log cabin (1)
> - Camping (1)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not know if this is quite OK, but is returning the expected results ... so at the moment this it is enough for me.

```
function my_custom_get_terms( $my_tax, $my_category, $show_all = true ){
    global $wpdb;
    global $pagename;

    $query = "SELECT Count(wp_posts.ID) AS my_term_count, wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id, wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_terms.name, wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.slug AS term_slug, wp_terms.term_group, wp_terms_1.slug
    FROM (((((wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id) INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID) INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS wp_term_relationships_1 ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships_1.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS wp_term_taxonomy_1 ON wp_term_relationships_1.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy_1.term_taxonomy_id) INNER JOIN wp_terms AS wp_terms_1 ON wp_term_taxonomy_1.term_id = wp_terms_1.term_id
    GROUP BY wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id, wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_terms.name, wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.slug, wp_terms.term_group, wp_terms_1.slug
    HAVING (((wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy)='$my_tax') AND ((wp_terms_1.slug) = '$my_category'))
    ORDER BY Count(wp_posts.ID) DESC";

    $datos = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
    echo "<ul>";
    $total = 0;
    foreach ( $datos as $dato ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/' . get_parent_page_slug() . '/' . $pagename . '/?tipo=' . $dato->term_slug . '">' . $dato->name . ' (' . $dato->my_term_count . ')</a></li>';
        $total += $dato->my_term_count;
    }

    if ( $show_all ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/' . get_parent_page_slug() . '/' . $pagename . '/">Todos (' . $total . ')</a></li>';
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}



my_custom_get_terms( 'tipo', get_parent_page_slug(), true );
```

thanks anyway